# Wpf without event handlers

Tags: wpf, events, handler

Edit:  I misread the assignment....  No event handlers because he doesn't want us working ahead, we're just to bind a set of data to controls to be displayed.

Small issue with homework in wpf.  We're building on a program each work, we're on binding right now.  The user enters data into a textbox, and it displays two sets of data into two datagrids.  Right now, what is displayed is hard coded instead of it pulling from a database.  I can get it to display the data and I can get it to display the correct data based on the textbox input, but we're not allowed to use event handlers.  So how can a button click be read without an event handler for it?

I can bind the textbox and the window's title so it changes as the text is changed within the textbox, but I can't get what is in the textbox.  It's possible I've overlooked something in the book, but I don't see how this is possible without event handlers for the button at least.

Comment: How about adding command to the button?

Comment: If the textbox is bound then then just get the value from the property.   What is the button supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not allowed to use events and are required to use a button in your interface, then commands are definitely the way to go.

Actually commands are the prefered solution for interaction over events since the release of WPF. As I am mostly developing using MVVM, I can't remember the last time I hooked on a button event.

Also every other way of linking your button to an interaction would be a dirty hack.

Maybe it is a bit of a step forward into your courses, but still it worth reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc785480.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to bind a button to a Command, that's what truly replaces the event

```
 <Button Command="{Binding ViewModel.YourCommand}"

 <Button Command="{Binding ViewModel.Cmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding ViewModel.CmdParam}"/>
```

The in the ViewModel, you do all the logic. Although you could put the command in YourView.xaml.cs, that depends on your MVVM design (meaning if you feel that like that functionality doesn't belong in the ViewModel)

Comment: He didn't specifically say we couldn't do this, but the reason we couldn't use event handlers is he doesn't want us focusing on that more than the data binding and we haven't covered event handlers, commands or triggers yet.  It seems more like an attempt to keep us from completing the project and then deleting what we don't need when we turn in our progress for the week, though.  I'll play around with this some next week.

Comment: commands are meant to replace such event's allowing for loose coupling between ViewModel and the View.

Answer (score 1):

You can multibind the datagrid to 2 things: your source data and the textbox. In the converter you can analyse the textbox's content and pick the right part of the data to display.

Comment: But that makes the required button useless, wouldn't it?  I have to click the button but I can't use an event handler.

Comment: yes. but is the button a part of the assignment? maybe you can do without it?

Comment: Yes, the button is required in the UI.  We can't use event handlers as they haven't been covered yet although we learned them in the prerequisite c# class.  Commands haven't been covered yet, either.  I do t see a way of doing it.

Comment: You can bind to the button's IsPressed :-) So you'll get your converter called as soon as the state changes. Kind of a hack, clearly.

Comment: Vlad, I think your answer's good, I don't think it's a hack, just another way to get what you need, and actually not in the ugly way, where you have to travel the visual tree, etc,etc. I think that's a good approach!